# Solve Ubercart's Javascript Reliance?

Tags: ubercart

Is their any way to solve Ubercart's Javascript Reliance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably depend a lot on what Ubercart features you needed to use. The simpler your needs, the easier it should be to get away without having to require Javascript.

For instance, if you just used a single payment method, especially one like Google Checkout which bypasses the regular Ubercart checkout system, you might be able to get away without using Javascript with few if any modifications to Ubercart.

Comment: The js thats my previous sites have been reliant on is for the shipping options calculations. Is I recall this is part of core so I dont know how you could get round it. Thanks

Comment: The name seems contradictory, but you might want to check out the Ajax Cart project on ubercart.org which supposedly works with Javascript disabled. I haven't tried it myself though: http://www.ubercart.org/project/uc_ajax_cart

Comment: I think its just to do with the cart block display, not actually fulfilling orders. Thanks